# Rails - How to get file path (not url path) for assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a weekly generator that zips some files. Some are assets in `app/assets/images/xxx.xxx` some are uploaded via Paperclip and in `public/system/env...`

The file paths I have start after `app`, without `/images/` or `public`.

I'll get something like `/assets/some.png` or `/system/production/xyz/some.jpg`, and these will be served fine as a URL path, but I want to collect them in a file.

How can I get the filepath of an asset?

---

I think this is an easier way to explain it.

Given the asset URI string, how can I find and get the asset's file path?

The asset URL path `/assets/logo.png` could be one of the files:

```
public/logo.png
public/assets/logo.png
app/assets/images/logo.png
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to ask here...you want to define an asset filepath i.e `app/"name-of-file"/xxx.xxx."file-type"`

Comment: @CallmeSurge I'd like a filepath that ruby ```File``` can open. Asset url paths dont need public/ or the ```/images``` part of assets/images/logo.png. But I want to get the files with a Ruby script on the server, not via HTTP

Answer (score 1):

In production, assets should be precompile and served from the public root folder /public/assets/logo.png